# how to get back stdout after piping it with dup?

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, file-descriptor

```
int mypipe[2];
pipe(mypipe);
int dupstdout=dup2(mypipe[1],1);
cout<<"hello";//not printed on terminal
fflush(stdout);
```

now how to print again on terminal or redirect mypipe[0] to stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    int mypipe[2];
    pipe(mypipe);
    int dupstdout=dup2(mypipe[1], 1);
    printf("hello");//not printed on terminal
    fflush(stdout);

    close(dupstdout);

    int fd = open("/dev/tty", O_WRONLY);
    stdout = fdopen(fd, "w");

    printf("hello again\n");
}
```

Anyway, it's better to not close `stdout`.

If a descriptor passed as a second argument to `dup2()` is already opened, `dup2()` closes it ignoring all errors. It's safer to use `close()` and `dup()` explicitly.

Comment: does new fd refers to actual /dev/pts/x?

Comment: Yes, `/dev/tty` is the controlling terminal of the process, i.e. the one in which the program was launched except if you detached it and reattached it to another terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Best to save a copy of standard out and restore it later.  If `dup2` closes your last copy of stdout, you might not be able to get it back (e.g., no controlling terminal, chroot'd and no access to /dev nor /proc, stdout was an anonymous pipe to begin with, etc.).

```
int mypipe[2];
pipe(mypipe);

int savstdout=dup(1); // save original stdout
dup2(mypipe[1], 1);
printf("hello");      // not printed on terminal
fflush(stdout);

dup2(savstdout, 1);   // restore original stdout
```